# Excel file generator : How to test resulting file

Tags: c#, file, unit-testing

I have write an excel (xls - 97-2003) file generator written in c#.
This is basically a wrapper over [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/).

Here is the interface of the generator :

```
   public interface IExcelGenerator
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// Add or replace a cell in the file.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="cell"></param>
      void AddCell(Cell cell);

      /// <summary>
      /// Create the file in memory.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="fileName"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      IFile CreateFile(string fileName);
   }
```

The final result of the generator is a `byte[]` (from the `IFile` object) that represent the raw file.

My `Cell` class is already unit-tested. Now I want to unit test the generator itself. I need to assert that the cell content is correct, as well as the format applied to the cell.

The only way I see is to generate a file in memory (a `byte[]`) and compare it to a file that I read on disk. But the simple action of opening a file in Excel and saving it adds a lot of weight to it (from 6K to 26K), even if nothing is changed inside. So the two arrays are almost never the same, even if the content of the cells is correct.

How can I assert that all the cells in both files have the same **value** and **format** ?

Comment: I've used the binary comparison technique you described and I'd recommend sticking with it. You are right that opening the file changes it's contents slightly and makes the comparison worthless, but the worse thing that will happen is getting false positives.  If you have source control setup it is easy enough to reset the file after opening it.

Comment: Also, if you have a build server that pulls from source control then you should be guaranteed to get an untainted version of the Excel spreadsheet during those unit tests.

Comment: Part of the problem is that Excel saves much more than the data (like your active cell and scrolling), unless you save it in a meta-data limiting format like CSV or TXT you can't simply do a byte comparison of the two.

Comment: @DanielCook that why it is important to save an untainted version of what IExcelGenerator produces for comparison purposes.  If you create a copy of that (or stash it in source control before opening) you can then open it up for a manual inspection of values and formatting. Once your manual inspection passes you are ready to use the untainted (read never opened) spreadsheet in unit tests.

Comment: BTW, I know this is cludgy and should really only be used when absolutely needed, but it will help ensure that any changes you or others make to spreadsheet code in the future that could negatively impact your client (a "good" value showing up red for example) does not slip through the cracks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that :

- The comparison file has to be generated with my generator, so there is no "extra" info in it such as column widht, row height. etc.
- If the file reside in source control, the simple fact of checking it in seems to affect the file (last modification date maybe?)
- I want to ensure that the generator will not break in the future, assuming that his actual state is correct.
- I do not want to write an xls reader just for test purpose, because I would have to test it too, so its like an infinite loop of test...
- I don't want to use the underlaying librairy (NPOI) to read the file in my test, because it could change in the future.

The solution I got is first generate the file and outputing the resulting `byte[]` to a base64 string.

```
byte[] bytes = //Result of the generator.
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
```

Then I put this string as `const` in my test, and I compare to it instead of reading a file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a sweeping unit test of all values and formatting could be choosing to focus on mission critical aspects.  When doing that you could unit test the final result by converting byte[] back to C# classes (via NPOI in your case), or you could simply unit test the objects before they are written to a file.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I prefer is to create a preformatted "template" spreadsheet that I open, populate with values, and then save as/stream, leaving the original template unchanged.  A manual inspection of the template is needed, but the template can contain formatting, including conditional formatting, formulas, etc. With this approach you may be able to get away with only comparing values, and comparing values is trivial, unlike validating formatting, mergedness of cells, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To test excel file you can read it as stream and just check it for example

```
 Stream result = your generated result;
 using var package = new ExcelPackage(result);
 //Cell A
 Assert.Equal("Company", package.Workbook.Worksheets["Matrix"].Cells["A2"].GetValue<string>());
```